# paypal sandbox account error status

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Hi I am trying to create paypal sandbox account. It created successfully and the status says "processing" but after minute status change to "error" and the error message is

> "Your sandbox account could not be created. Delete it and try again."

but I can't delete it either. What will be problem.
Thank you for your any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved at our end. Kindly check and let us know if you are still persisting the same issue.

Comment: Facing the same issue.